# vbscript close object before set again

Tags: vbscript

I have recently inherited a DTS package written in VBScript, i have not had a lot of exposure to VBS and wanted to check if the function where i have added the ' Do i need a rs1.close here comment below should be closing the rs1 object before setting it again?.

```
Function Proc_Amend()
On error resume next
  dtspackagelog.writestringtolog "Start Proc_Amend at " & Time
' Check record to be amended exists
  set rs1 = cn1.execute("SELECT StatusFlag from wmLoadId where LoadID='" & iarray(1) & _
"' and OrderNumber='" & iarray(2) & "' and OrderLineNumber='" & iarray(4) & "' and OrderReleaseNumber='" & iarray(5) & "'")
  If rs1.eof then
    Err.Raise 9994 , , "Record to be amended DOES NOT exist"
    Call ErrHand(err.number,err.description)
  Else
    If UCASE(rs1.fields("StatusFlag").value) = "PENDING" Then
      iarray(14) = "PENDING"
    End If
    ' Do i need a rs1.close here
    set rs1 = cn1.execute("UPDATE wmLoadId set OrderWeight = " & iarray(9) & ",StatusFlag='" & iarray(14) & "',Timestamp = getdate() where LoadID='" & iarray(1) & _
"' and OrderNumber='" & iarray(2) & "' and OrderLineNumber='" & iarray(4) & "' and OrderReleaseNumber='" & iarray(5) & "'")
    If Err Then
' An error occurred so process
      Call ErrHand(err.number,err.description)
    End If
' Check and update planned_ship_date (if reqd.)
    ' Do i need a rs1.close here
    set rs1 = cn1.execute("SELECT planned_ship_date from Add_Info where LoadID='" & iarray(1) & _
"' and OrderNumber='" & iarray(2) & "' and OrderLineNumber='" & iarray(4) & "' and OrderReleaseNumber='" & iarray(5) & "'")
    If rs1.eof then
      Err.Raise 9988 , , "No Add_Info record exists to update"
      Call ErrHand(err.number,err.description)
    Else
      cm.CommandText="select convert(varchar(10),wanted_delivery_date,103) AS PlanShip  from OPENQUERY(DB33,'select wanted_delivery_date from CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE_TAB where order_no=''" & iarray(2)  & _
"'' and LINE_NO = ''" & iarray(4) & "'' AND REL_NO = ''" & iarray(5) & "'' ' ) "
      dtspackagelog.writestringtolog  "Planned_Ship_Date (amend) command is " &  cm.CommandText
      set rs = cm.execute()
      dtspackagelog.writestringtolog  "Err status after Planned_Ship_Date (amend) command is " &  err.number & " at " & Time
      if rs.eof then
        On Error Resume Next
        dtspackagelog.writestringtolog "No CUSTOMER_ORDER record found for order line (amend) at " & Time
        Err.Raise 9987 , , "No CUSTOMER_ORDER record found for order line (amend) " & iarray(2) & " / " & iarray(4) & " / " & iarray(5)
        Call ErrHand(err.number,err.description)
      else
        planship = rs.Fields("PlanShip").value
        rs.close
      End If
      dtspackagelog.writestringtolog  "PlanShip (amend) set to " & planship & " at " & Time
      If rs1.fields("planned_ship_date").value <> planship Then
        dtspackagelog.writestringtolog  "Update PlanShip from " & rs1.fields("planned_ship_date").value & " to " & planship & " at " & Time
        ' Do i need a rs1.close here
        set rs1 = cn1.execute("UPDATE Add_Info set planned_ship_date = '" & planship & "' where LoadID='" & iarray(1) & _
"' and OrderNumber='" & iarray(2) & "' and OrderLineNumber='" & iarray(4) & "' and OrderReleaseNumber='" & iarray(5) & "'")
        If Err Then
' An error occurred so process
          Call ErrHand(err.number,err.description)
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
  dtspackagelog.writestringtolog "Finish Proc_Amend at " & Time
End Function
```